# New SDK update can not create Hello World example at first

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Well normaly when I am openning new project there was no problem a hello world aplication automaticly was created. but today When I try to open a new Android project Eclips dont create main activity java files and manifest

This is all my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kolp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

And this is all my outline. You can see src folder is empty!

[image]

Comment: You can create it manually na. Create a package and then class. What is the big deal with that?

Comment: yeah may be you are right but I want to learn What is the reason? What was changed? what is wrong?

Comment: Try, Restarting eclipse.